# How to bypass incomplete segue bug

Tags: swift, xcode

I think I have run into a bug with Xcode itself and was hoping to find some help on bypassing the issue somehow. I have a video playing with AVKit and I wanted to segue to another view controller when it finished. I found that the video view controller had to be dismissed before the segue could be called so I added that. The end of the video matches with the new view controller so I want the switch to be smooth, so I have animated: false for the dismiss, this is what causes the issue. if animated is set to true the segue runs fine, but if it is set to false the segue doesn't fully complete, the video is disabled and I can see the old view controller, the segue only takes effect if I tap the screen, and the new view controller appears.
Here is that code

```
animPlayer.dismiss(animated: false)

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BackpackSegue", sender: self)
```

Even weirder the code runs perfectly fine on a physical ipad, so it must be a simulator bug

Edit: Here is the entire swift file, I am new to this so tell me if you need something else from the project.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class FrontDoorOpen: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    }
    */
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return true
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var SegueImage: UIImageView!
    let animPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()

    @IBAction func DoorCloseSegue(_ sender: Any) {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DoorClose", ofType: "avi", inDirectory: "SegueAnimations")
        {
            let SegueAnimation = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))


            animPlayer.player = SegueAnimation
            animPlayer.showsPlaybackControls = false
            animPlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
             NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.finishVideo), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

            present(animPlayer, animated: false, completion:
        {
                SegueAnimation.play()
        })
        }
        SegueImage.isHidden = false
    }
    @objc func finishVideo()
    {
        animPlayer.dismiss(animated: false)
        // Simulator Pauses Here !!
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "DoorCloseSegue", sender: self)

    }
}
```

After experimenting some more the simulator seems to pause between the dismiss and segue, the segue only occurs with a click

Comment: Please share more code for better explanation?

Comment: Here is the entire swift file, I am new to this so tell me if you need something else from the project.